# How to align icon to the left with text to the right?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to correctly align the icon on the left side with the text on the right side.

```css
.firm-info {
  width: 280px;
}
.firm-info ul {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.firm-info ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.firm-info ul li i {
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 10px;
}
.firm-info p {
  float: left;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="firm-info">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas venenatis cursus nulla, tempus porttitor ex fringilla id. Donec cras amet.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

The final version should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should reset the default top margin on the `p` tag, and increase the width of the `i` tag, or simply remove the width and use some right padding or margin for spacing.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jc3eb2jr/)**

```css
.firm-info {
  width: 280px;
}
.firm-info ul {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.firm-info ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.firm-info ul li i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.firm-info ul li p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="firm-info">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas venenatis cursus nulla, tempus porttitor.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
      <p>Bla</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
      <p>Bla</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that!